# Add post type titles in customizer dropdown list

Tags: theme-customizer, dropdown

I want to add the list of my available contact forms (created in contact forms 7) to a dropdown in the customizer.

Here is the code I used:

```
function contact_form_list() {
    $args = array('post_type' => 'wpcf7_contact_form');
    $cf7forms = get_posts( $args );
    foreach($cf7forms as $cf7form) {
            return $cf7form->post_title;
    }
}

// Add setting and control for Contact section

$wp_customize->add_setting( 'contact_list', array(
    'transport' => 'postMessage'
));
$wp_customize->add_control( 'contact_list', array(
    'label'    => esc_html__( 'Contact form', 'mytheme' ),
    'type'     => 'select',
    'section'  => 'contact_section',
    'priority' => 4,
    'choices'  => contact_form_list()
));
```

It displays the dropdown but there is no choice. It is empty.

What am I doing wrong? Or is it the wrong way to do so?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 7):

Ok I found it, here is the answer for next ones who are looking for the same thing:

```
$cf7forms_list = array();
$args = array('post_type' => 'wpcf7_contact_form');
$cf7forms = get_posts( $args ); 
foreach($cf7forms as $cf7form) {
    $cf7forms_list[$cf7form->post_title] = $cf7form->post_title;
}

$wp_customize->add_setting( 'contact_list_section', array(
    'transport' => 'postMessage'
));
$wp_customize->add_control( 'contact_list_section', array(
    'label'    => esc_html__( 'Contact form', 'mytheme' ),
    'type'     => 'select',
    'section'  => 'contact_section',
    'priority' => 4,
    'choices'  => $cf7forms_list,
));
```

Comment: In the event you want to return more than 5 though line 2 should be changed to "$args = array('post_type' => 'wpcf7_contact_form', 'posts_per_page'   => 999); Otherwise get_posts will only give you back 5 posts and leave you scratching your head.